# InitializeComponent not available in this context

Tags: c#, class, xaml, xamarin

I have renamed

OSCCellEdit.xaml->OSCCell.xaml.cs

from

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class OSCCellEditor : ContentPage
    {
        public OSCCellEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

to

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class OSCCellEdit : ContentPage
    {
        public OSCCellEdit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

And

OSCCellEdit.xaml from

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.OSCCellEditor" Title="{Binding Name}">
```

to

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.OSCCellEdit" Title="{Binding Name}">
```

Now the compiler tells me: "The name 'InitalizeComponent' is not available in the current context".

Could anybody please tell me why this might be happening and how to fix this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the Complier dependency in .csproj file?

```
<Compile Include="OSCCell.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>OSCCell.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

It should be like this xaml.cs dependent on xaml file make sure the name matched in your project.

If it still not works delete bin and obj file and build again.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It turned out that I had to activate the option "Include strings" in the Rename dialog.